# How to ban a ip with fail2ban using fail2ban-client and actionban

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I am on fail2ban 0.8.3 and I would like to ban an ip address after reloading fail2ban.

I tried:

```
fail2ban-client get myjail actionban ip
```

after that I get an empty line in bash and `fail2ban status myjail` shows not banned ips

How do I properly put an ip into a jail via fail2ban-client?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing jail `myjail` then

```
fail2ban-client set myjail banip <IP>
```

should do what you want.

Comment: I am sorry but my fail2ban does not have that command. Please note that I am on 0.8.3 !